# "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Tags: json, swift, decoding

I'm having a few issues with parsing data through a local JSON file and I'm not able to figure out why. I keep getting an error:

> Error parsing JSON data: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

The JSON file that I'm trying to use is located here: https://github.com/erik-sytnyk/movies-list/blob/master/db.json

The struct I'm using is this:

```
import Foundation

struct MovieData: Codable {
    let genres: [String]
    let movies: [movies]
}

struct movies: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let year: String
    let runtime: String
    let director: String
    let actors: String
    let plot: String
    let posterUrl: String
}
```

This is my dataModel to parse the data:

```
import Foundation

final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var Film: [movies] = load("moviez.json")
}

func load<V:Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> V {
    let data: Data
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
            else
    {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle")
    }
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch{
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle: \n\(error)")
    }
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(V.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(V.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

This is the view I'm trying to display the data on:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MovieDetail: View {
    var movie: movies
    var body: some View {
        Text(movie.director)
    }
}

struct MovieDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovieDetail(movie: ModelData().Film[0])
    }
}
```

I'm expecting this to show the director info but I keep getting the parse error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please update the question with the exact parse-error.

Comment: Its already on there at top but here it is again: error: Error parsing JSON data: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: Update your question with the complete output of the `fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(V.self):\n\(error)")` line.

Comment: `@Published var Film: [movies] = load("moviez.json")`,here is the error. `Film` is not an array of `movies` but a `MovieData`. So either change the type or perhaps better add an `init` where you call `load` and then extract the movie array from the result. Off topic but `movies` should really be named `Movie`.

Comment: if one of you don't mind please can you send me an example code, I'm quite new to this so I don't clearly understand init() or where do i put it and stuff, thank you for everyones response so far.

Comment: I've updated the error in title

Comment: Share the FULL error message in the question, not only in the title of the question (which is limited). It has important informations.

Comment: `var Film: [movies] = load("moviez.json")` might be `var Film: MovieData = load("moviez.json")`, or maybe `var Film: [movies] = load("moviez.json").movies`

Comment: Hi Larme,
Thank you so much, changing it to  var Film: MovieData = load("moviez.json") did the trick, i really appreciate you for helping out. Would you please add this as an answer so I can credit you for the answer? Thanks again!

Comment: I'd recommend to not use `load()`, directly on the property, but on the `init()`, because it's hiding the fact that's it's failing there. it's harder for beginner to find the issue. See vadian's answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all – as mentioned in the comments – name structs always uppercase and in singular form if they are primarily used in an array. On the other hand name properties always lowercase and in plural form if they represent *multiple items*.

```
struct MovieData: Decodable {
    let genres: [String]
    let movies: [Movie]
}

struct Movie: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let year: String
    let runtime: String
    let director: String
    let actors: String
    let plot: String
    let posterUrl: URL // can directly be decoded as URL
 }
```

The type mismatch error occurs because you annotate `[movies]` (***expected to decode array***) but the root object is `MovieData` (***found a dictionary instead***).

A reasonable solution is to add an `init` method

```
final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var movies = [Movie]()


    init() {
       let movieData : MovieData = load("moviez.json")
       movies = movieData.movies
    }

    func load<V:Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> V { ...
}
```